# Removing last element from array and returning it

Tags: java

My task was to implement on my own array where I can add elements and then removing the first element and returning it and the same goes with the last element. Since I'm not allowed to use any built-in functions such array.copyOf, ArrayList or anything else which uses java.util package my knowledge is limited.

My first solution was to use similar code for both takeFirst() and takeLast() methods and it worked, but I'd like to know if there's any other and better solution for removing last element and returning it.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class MyQueue {

    private int[] data = new int[1000];

    // add new element to the end of queue
    public void add(int i) {
        if(size() == 0){
            data[0] = i;
        }else {
            data[size()] = i;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for(int elem: data) {
            if(elem != 0) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }

    // removes first element and returns it
    public int takeFirst() {
        int firstItem = data[0];

        int[] temp = new int[size() - 1]; // allocate proper size
        for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++){
            temp[i-1] = data[i]; // i-1 for temp array
        }
        data = temp;
        return firstItem;
    }

    // removes last element and returns it
    public int takeLast() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I could use this (works and test is going through), but it is basically a dublicate to takeFirst() method:

```
// removes last element and returns it
    public int takeLast() {
        int lastItem = data[size() - 1];
        int[] temp = new int[size() - 1]; // allocate proper size
        for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++){
            temp[i-1] = data[i]; // i-1 for temp array
        }
        data = temp;
        return lastItem;
    }
```

And the given test:

````
@Test
    public void queueUsageExample() {
        MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();

        queue.add(1);
        queue.add(3);
        queue.add(5);

        assertThat(queue.size(), is(3));

        assertThat(queue.takeFirst(), is(1));
        assertThat(queue.takeFirst(), is(3));
        assertThat(queue.takeLast(), is(5));

        assertThat(queue.size(), is(0));
    }```
````

Comment: Keep a index field as well in class Queue, to keep track till where the array is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code of `takeFirst` and `takeLast` is similar, then a separate method `removeAt` could be implemented and invoked from the mentioned methods:

```java
public int takeFirst() {
    return removeAt(0, 1); // keeping data starting from index 1
}

public int takeLast() {
    return removeAt(size() - 1, 0); // keeping data starting from index 0
}

private int removeAt(int index, int keepFrom) {
    int removedItem = data[index];
    int newSize = size() - 1;

    int[] tmp = new int[newSize];
    for (int i = 0, j = keepFrom; i < newSize; i++, j++) {
        tmp[i] = data[j++];
    }
    data = tmp;

    return removedItem;
}
```

Comment: Does the "size = newSize;" the line should be declared before since I don't use size variable  only size() method? :)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that, and thought `size` is a field.  However, I'm also not sure if the resize is always needed, possibly, a couple of indexes to refer the first and the last elements should be used, along with setting `0` to the appropriate elements.